# Nested Loops and New Child Elements

Tags: jquery, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm writing a simple weather application and am stuck with the for loops.  The idea is to get the weather for a small array of locations and to load the forecast for each into its own div.  Here's the code so far:

```
$(function () {
    var z = ["location ID1", "location ID2", etc.];
    var n = ["location name1", "location name2", etc];
    for (j = 0; j<z.length; j++) {
        weatherQuery = 'SELECT * FROM rss WHERE url="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/' + z[j] + '_c.xml"';
        $('#weatherData').append($('<div/>', {id: 'c' + j}));
        $('#c' + j + '').append('' + n[j] + '');
        var weatherUrl = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(weatherQuery) + '&format=json';
        $.getJSON(weatherUrl + '&callback=?', function (data) {
            var weatherForecasts = data.query.results.item.forecast;
            for (i=0; i<weatherForecasts.length; i++) {
                var code = weatherForecasts[i].code;
                $('#c' + j + '').append('<table style = border:none><tr><td class = weather-date>' + weatherForecasts[i].day + '</td><td class = weather-icon style = background-position:-' + (61 * code ) + 'px 0px></td><td class = weather-min>' + weatherForecasts[i].low + '°</td><td class = weather-max>' + weatherForecasts[i].high + '°</td></tr></table>');              
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

As far as I can tell from Firebug, the first part works - the correct weather data is being retrieved and the new divs are being created in the parent div.  The correct location names are also being appended to each of the new divs.  Were it falls down is in appending the weather data to each div. What is the correct way to identify the child div in the second (last) append statement so that there is one iteration of the weather data parsing loop for each div? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (j = 0; j<z.length; j++) {
    $.getJSON(..., function (data) {
        $('#c' + j + '').append(...
```

The loop executes `z.length` times, starting up `z.length` AJAX requests, and completes with `j` being equal to `z.length` terminating the loop.

Then, much later (because the ‘A’ in AJAX means ‘asyncronous’) the requests complete and each of the callback functions is called. They use `j` to choose which div to append their results to. But `j` is still `z.length` as it was back when the loop finished. Creating a function with a closure over a variable doesn't mean that the value of the variable is remembered from the point the function was created; each function has a reference to the same `j`.

(Actually you don't have a closure at all because your loop variables `j` and `i` aren't declared `var`, so they're accidental global variables.)

You can remember the value of a local variable when creating a function by wrapping it in a separate function with that variable in (or using `function.bind` in ECMAScript 5). A simple way of doing that is to use a callback-function-based loop instead of a `for`:

```
var places = [
    {id: 'location1', name: 'Location One'},
    ...
];

$.each(places, function(place_i, place) {
    var yql = 'SELECT * FROM rss WHERE url="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/' + encodeURIComponent(place.id) + '_c.xml"';
    var div = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'c'+place_i)).text(place.name);
    $('#weatherData').append(div);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
        data: {q: yql, format: 'json'},
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    ).done(function(json) {
        var forecasts = data.query.results.item.forecast;
        var table = $('<table style="border: none">'); // prefer class/stylesheet
        $.each(forecasts, function(forecast_i, forecast) {
            table.append($('<tr>').append(
                $('<td class="weather-date">').text(forecast.day)
            ).append(
                $('<td class="weather-icon">').css('background-position', forecast.code*-61 + 'px 0')
            ).append(
                $('<td class="weather-min">').text(forecast.low+'°')
            ).append(
                $('<td class="weather-max">').text(forecast.high+'°')
            ));
        });
        div.html(table);
    });
});
```

notes:

- use jQuery's automatic conversion of data parameters to avoid having to call `encodeURIComponent` manually on the JSON URL.
- avoid sticking together HTML content from string variables. It fails for HTML-special characters and may introduce security problems (XSS). For setting text content, use jQuery `text()`.
- you probably don't need to give the element an `id` at all if you keep a reference to it in a JS variable like this.

Comment: Thanks!  That works (and is a valuable lesson) - I just had to make 2 changes: 1. Add in a `}` at the end of the ajax function, and switch `div.html(table)` to `div.append(table)` to avoid the names being deleted when the json data was loaded.